# Is there any reward specific to Loot Boxes that cannot be obtained otherwise?

Tags: overwatch

Is there anything in Loot Boxes, whether they be common or Legendary, that I cannot get by spending coins on them in the Hero Gallery page in Overwatch?

Is everything available for purchase of coins in Overwatch? Or are some rewards solely limited to Loot Boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, every piece of unlockable loot comes from the loot boxes (and/or bought from coins) with the exception of the Pre-order and Origins edition skins. (I'm betting there will be a Blizzcon 2016 one as well)

Comment: And of course, coins only come from boxes.

Comment: You forgot about player icons, which cannot be purchased with coins and only comes from loot boxes.

Answer (score 10):

Player icons (the little picture next to your name, shown on top right, selected from the career profile menu) are locked to loot boxes and cannot be purchased with coins.